# Trying to remove with space in a product page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to remove white space on a page but I don't understand where it coming from.
The website Is built on the WordPress platform
I've attached a screenshot of the whitespace.
basically, I want to remove the whitespace so the text will align with the image on the same line.
[image]

Here is a URL of the product page: [https://medton-hedim.co.il/product/clean-aid-%d7%a1%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%99-%d7%9c%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%95%d7%99-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%99/](https://medton-hedim.co.il/product/clean-aid-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
.summary.entry-summary {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div class="summary entry-summary" style="display:flex">
```